# How can I force my excel data into less columns

Tags: excel, data-cleaning

I have a set of company data that is 3500 rows. I am trying to put this data in a format so that I can run statistical analysis. My problem is that I want to take all the data in columns C:D and transpose them. I know how to transpose the data but Now my data is 3000 columns wide. How can I take this data and make it so that the transposed data will be restricted to 5 columns and that each additional column would be put below the next. In the image below the green is the format I want and the red is all of the information that was transposed. I want this red information to go to the green columns. See Image for clearer description:
[image]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You say you need to transpose your data, but when transposed it's too wide.  It's hard to suggest how else you should organize it without knowing *exactly* what you want to do with it.

Comment: @TimWilliams , from the image, it appears it's not transposed, but each section gets stacked one above the other, so first 5 columns on 1 line, then next 5 columns, etc